# Can Someone Editing my ajax code

Tags: ajax, laravel

when I am using ajax in laravel to post if the button is clicked very fast and to much it will cause some of the posts to finish updating the database faster than others, which cuases a counter field in my database to have wrong data, I am using async:false, my question is can a user edit my ajax in there browser and send the ajax code with out async:false?

Comment: there is nothing stopping anyone from sending any request they want at any time

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can be done, use post request so it can't be injected because it checks CSRF session.